# How to repaint a JPanel to update position of a graphics object?

Tags: java, keylistener

I'm testing out KeyListener for a Tetris project I am working on. My main problem is that I cannot get the JPanel to repaint to update the rectangle's position after pressing a key. The JPanel is embedded into a JFrame, so I'm not sure whether to update the panel or the frame. Here's the code:

```
public class mainBoardTest extends JPanel implements KeyListener { 
    private Rectangle rect;
    public mainBoardTest() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 800));
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}


public void init() {
    this.addKeyListener(this);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    //super.paintComponent(g);
    rect = new Rectangle(0,0,50,50);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fill(rect);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x + 2, rect.y);
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x - 2, rect.y);
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y - 2);
    }
    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        rect.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y + 2);
    }
    repaint(); //does not repaint
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its that all the code related to the panel and frame? if yes its look like there are missing few things.

There is already an answer related to move an object when pressing keys, this the link

[how to move an object in a JPanel using the arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442009/how-to-move-an-object-in-a-jpanel-using-the-arrow-keys)

maybe that can help you

Answer (score 0):

In your paint() method, you create a new Rectangle every time you call it, with a default location. That replaces whatever you change you made in your keyPressed handler.